# How to overcome "You cannot enter another instance of this map yet"?

Tags: rift

I'm on the quest [The End of Salvarola](http://rift.magelo.com/en/quest/-2391686/The-End-of-Salvarola) and am attempting to go up the elevator to the throne room.  I was grouped with a friend who got the message in the title while I was able to enter (see [this related forum post](http://forums.riftgame.com/game-discussions/adventures-telara/369092-quest-bug-end-salvarola-cant-enter-instance-friends.html)), so we split up which kicked me out of the instance.  I re-entered but the quest was messed up (the NPCs were acting like they were on the first step, but I was on the second) so I left the instance again and reset the quest.  Now when I try to enter (still solo) I'm constantly getting the same error message that my groupmate originally did.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the phase difficulty setting (from the right-click menu on my portrait) reset the instance, and I was then allowed to re-enter.  Presumably waiting an hour or however long the rate limiter deemed I needed to wait would also have worked, but that's incredibly annoying.